# Can't access site (or admin) - no error messages

Tags: wordpress

Since a couple of days ago our info site (WP) isn't working at all, which is strange because we haven't done any changes lately whatsoever. No error messages shows up and what happens is that it times out (same with admin interface).

It started with a couple of strange error messages that was connected to a couple of plugins (Google maps ready and YouTube widget responsive) and after disabling them through FTP they dissapeared but instead the site just load and load and then times out.

Because no error message is shown and we're not able to access the admin interface it is very hard to know what's wrong here. Does anyone have any idea what could cause this problem?

The site: [inteokej.se/info](http://www.inteokej.se/info)

Comment: try disabling all plugins and switch to default theme. Then enable plugin one by one to see which one is causing the problem.

Comment: what I can see is your site is having redirection loop. inteokej.se/info redirects to www.inteokej.se/info and vise versa. try to resolve that.

Comment: @mevius, yes if admin is not accessible any more then we do not have any other way to do that.

Comment: set WP_DEBUG is true in wp-config.file

Comment: @rnevius you can switch themes and deactivate plugins without admin interface. ;-)

Comment: @Avinash: You solved the problem, it was a redirection loop that caused the problem and now the site works. You can convert the comment to an answer so I can accept it :) Thanks!

Comment: @holyredbeard Added as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I can see is your site is having redirection loop. inteokej.se/info redirects to www.inteokej.se/info and vise versa. try to resolve that.